# How do i substr certain string from a text line and get the remaining

Tags: php, text, substr

I have a text line of `12345678910` in my solution, I want to get `8910` in one line using the function `substr()` I have tried:

```
$text = "12345678910";
$pay = substr($text,0,7);
echo $pay;
```

But I get `1234567` expected `8910`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use -4 as the second parameter.

`echo substr("1234567890", -4);`

Answer (score 2):

You've misread the manual, the second parameter is the starting position and the third is the length. So you are telling it to start at the start of the string and go 7 characters in. You could do:

```
$pay = substr($text,7);
```

or

```
$pay = substr($text,7, 4);
```

or the negative as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```
<?php
$text = "12345678910";
$pay = substr($text,7);
echo $pay;
```